# What is the reasoning Chrome resolves double dot in URI?

Tags: google-chrome, url

Today I've came across an interesting Google Chrome behaviour.

Let's say that I have a web App that lets us see the information about the user:

```
http://app.com/user/Rok/info
```

Now let's assume we have an user named `..`. When we visit his information page,

```
http://app.com/user/../info
```

you can see in the Developer Tools that the browser makes the request to `app.com/info`.

Why is the browser doing that? It should **pass this decision to the server.**

Novadays, URIs are no longer directly bound to the filesystem. I was wondering whether there is a spec that targets this specific.

Comment: No, this is not opinion based, I'm asking whether there is a Spec targeting this. Read the question, please.

Comment: You say Chrome's behavior is "clearly wrong" and that in your opinion it's "unacceptable". This belongs in a bug report to Google or the Chromium project, not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: For better or worse, URLs have always been treated as a hierarchical path. Removing dot-segments is important for resolving relative paths and normalizing URLs.

Comment: Yes, but is there a reason for browser to do that? Server - maybe - but browser?

Comment: So what did you do in the end? And I don't see how this type of "resolving" and "normalizing" might be useful...(?!). I have the same problem that I can't link to a stylesheet file using dotdots since the browser(Chrome) seems to be removing it! That's weird because exactly the same relative paths work for importing font files and images!

Comment: @aderchox Have you considered filing a bug in the Chromium bug tracker?

Comment: @RokKralj, I'm not sure if I remember clearly as it's been a while since then, but I think it was a mistake on my own side. I was trying to make the web server access a file outside the web root (outside of where it was set to serve files, aka "web server root"), so it correctly chopped those `..`s to avoid it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was just trying to figure this out for myself, and it looks like it's specifically addressed in [RFC 3986, § 5.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4):

> The pseudocode also refers to a `remove_dot_segments` routine for
> interpreting and removing the special `.` and `..` complete path
> segments from a referenced path.  This is done after the path is
> extracted from a reference, whether or not the path was relative, in
> order to remove any invalid or extraneous dot-segments prior to
> forming the target URI.
>
> […]
>
> Note that *dot-segments* are intended for use in URI references to
> express an identifier relative to the hierarchy of names in the base
> URI.  The `remove_dot_segments` algorithm respects that hierarchy by
> removing extra *dot-segments* rather than treat them as an error or
> leaving them to be misinterpreted by dereference implementations.

Comment: [Section 5.2.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) for the impatient